# Turn nested objects into single array of values

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have some json data which looks like this:

```
{ 
'harry-test-com': { 'quoteID234324': {'day': 'tuesday', 'cost':'1000'}},
'sam-imaginarydomain-com': {
'quoteID13211': {'day': 'wednesday', 'cost': '500'},
'quoteID534534': {'day': 'monday', 'cost': '300'}
 }
};
```

So basically our quotes are arranged by user for easy filtering. However, on one page I'd like to display ALL the quotes in a list. So I'd like to go through each user, grab their quotes, and add them to an object sorted by keys, like this:

```
'quoteID234324': {'day': 'tuesday', 'cost':'1000'}, 
'quoteID13211': {'day': 'wednesday', 'cost': '500'},
'quoteID534534': {'day': 'monday', 'cost': '300'}
```

I think lodash would no doubt be useful for this, but I just have no clue where to begin?? Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the object into a new object using `Object.keys()` and `Object.assign()`:

```js
const obj = {
  'harry-test-com': {
    'quoteID234324': {
      'day': 'tuesday',
      'cost': '1000'
    }
  },
  'sam-imaginarydomain-com': {
    'quoteID13211': {
      'day': 'wednesday',
      'cost': '500'
    },
    'quoteID534534': {
      'day': 'monday',
      'cost': '300'
    }
  }
};

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((days, user) => Object.assign(days, obj[user]), {});

console.log(result);
```

A less supported option is to use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) with `Object.assign`:

```js
const obj = {
  'harry-test-com': {
    'quoteID234324': {
      'day': 'tuesday',
      'cost': '1000'
    }
  },
  'sam-imaginarydomain-com': {
    'quoteID13211': {
      'day': 'wednesday',
      'cost': '500'
    },
    'quoteID534534': {
      'day': 'monday',
      'cost': '300'
    }
  }
};

const result = Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(obj));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Amazing that's just what I needed thank you so much!

Comment: I went with the second as it's a little more concise as we may be adding quite a few keys within each object. However eslint yelled at me to use spread so I researched that and ended up with this:  ` const result = Object.assign(...Object.values(obj)); `

Comment: Updated the answer to create a new object, so it won't mutate the original data ('harry-test-com' object).

Comment: Amazing! I've just been trying to figure out why my componentWillReceiveProps wasn't firing and figured it must be something to do with mutating the state! Lifesaver...

Comment: Hmm, it's still not firing. My redux reducer is structured like this:              const quotes = action.payload;
      const quotesList = Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(quotes));
        return { ...state, quotesList };    Any idea why thats not causing the componentWillReceiverProps to fire?

Comment: Yes It's really really strange... Part of the whole 're-write the object in state' approach that's encouraged was I believed to trigger the component into recognising new props from mapStateToProps and not considering the objects to be the same... Wonder what's going on. I'll try moving all my list logic to the render method even though I'm not sure if that's encouraged

Comment: Oh wow, I'm an idiot! I'd changed my piece of state to 'quotesList' but was still referring to 'quotes' in my mapStateToProps... hence no update. SO SORRY for wasting your time! All is working perfectly now. Thanks again a million for your help!

Comment: bad data organization! its too difficult to manipulate. use objects if it really necessary! your data must looks like 
var arr = [
    {
        user: 'harry-test-com',
        quotes: [
            {
                id: 'quoteID234324',
                day: 'tuesday',
                cost: '1000'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        user: 'sam-imaginarydomain-com',
        quotes: [
            {
                id: 'quoteID13211',
                day: 'wednesday',
                cost: '500'
            },
           {...}
        ]
    }
]

Comment: @stasovlas I'm trying to go with a flat data structure as recommended by Firebase, could you please elaborate on why that's a bad idea? I want to be able to pull data from various nodes independently without having to download all the child data for each user in order to display all the quotes (or whatever else I might want to display) hence the recursive structure suggested by them. But I genuinely would like to know if that's a bad idea. Thanks

Comment: @SamMatthews ohh, sorry, i did not know what it is database structure, i was wrong

Comment: No worries, it can be a pain this structure but ultimately it's just to save the total data needing to go back and forwards to the database